# how to convert the string to char in objective C

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion

how to convert the string to char in objective C. The following is the code i am using,

```
NSString *param = [paramsToPass objectAtIndex:0]
[class gseInit:&getData];
[class gseCom:param];
NSLog(@"%@", param);
```

at line No.3, I get the following warning,

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString*' to parameter of type
>   'char*'.

so how to over come the above warning.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe you should read the doc for NSString??

Comment: Read this http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to get to UTF-8 representation of the `NSString`:

```
NSString *param = [paramsToPass objectAtIndex:0]
[class gseInit:&getData];
[class gseCom:[param UTF8String]];
NSLog(@"%@", param);
```

However that will only work if `gseCom:` is **not** updating the string (i.e. param is `const char *`).  The only way to really know this is to read the documentation for the class (you don't mention what the class is, so I can't help there).

If it's not updating the parameter, and `gseCom` is mistakenly defined as accepting a `char *`, rather than a `const char *`, then you can simply cast it to the correct type:

```
[class gseCom:(char *)[param UTF8String]];
```

However if it's updating `param`, then you will need to give it a buffer to work with:

```
[class gseInit:&getData];

NSString *param = [paramsToPass objectAtIndex:0]

// Create a buffer containing the c-string (in UTF-8)
#define BUFSIZ 256    // This size depends on what the string could hold
char cparam[BUFSIZ];
[param getCString:cparam maxLength:BUFSIZ encoding:NSUTF8Encoding];

// Let the method update the string
NSLog(@"before %s", cparam);
[class gseCom:cparam];
NSLog(@"after %s", cparam);
```

Comment: hi trojanfoe,thanks for help,after using your code for converting i am getting the following warning,how to overcome this,i checked through google,i was not able to get the proper solution, the warning is, Sending 'const char*' to parameter of type 'char*' discards qualifiers. this warning could look simple to you, but i am new to the objective C,thanks in advance.

Comment: @shasha I have updated my answer with ways of solving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *param = [paramsToPass objectAtIndex:0]
[class gseInit:&getData];
[class gseCom:[param cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding]];
NSLog(@"%@", param);
```

[method documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/cStringUsingEncoding%3a)

Comment: hi Regexident,thanks for help,after using your code for converting i am getting the following warning,how to overcome this,i checked through google,i was not able to get the proper solution, the warning is, Sending 'const char*' to parameter of type 'char*' discards qualifiers. this warning could look simple to you, but i am new to the objective C,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *str = @"Hello";
char h = [str characterAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%c", h);
```

Comment: He actually wants a `char *` rather than a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [Creating and Converting String Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html), from Apple developers site.